# Reveal.js - <source> element has no “src” attribute

Tags: javascript, firefox, reveal.js

I am designing a Reveal.js presentation. I am getting these warnings in the console:

```
<source> element has no “src” attribute. Media resource load failed.
All candidate resources failed to load. Media load paused.
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with Firefox 52. I don't get these warning from Chrome. Also, the audio is working properly as far as I can tell.

This is how I am setting my audio:

```
document.getElementById("audio4").innerHTML = "<source data-src='../../learn/audio/lesson" + lesson_number + "/" + a_file + ".mp3' type='audio/mpeg'>";
```

So as you can see, I am using *data-src* (lazy-loading) instead of *src*. How can I get rid of those warnings and still use lazy-loading?

---

Update:

- I was just looking over some of the code in the reveal.js file. It changes the `data-src` to `src` automatically for the next slide, and it also calls the `.load()` function right after that.
- I tried the HTML tag *preload* but that didn't have any effect on the warnings.

Comment: after *lazy-loading* is done (when you've set the real src) call your mediaElement (here `<audio>` ?) `.load()` method. But you know there is the [`preload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attr-preload) attribute ?, even though browsers don't have to follow it...

Comment: lazy-loading is done when the presentation is done. On slide 1, the audio for slide 2 is loaded. On slide 2, the audio for slide 3 is loaded, ect...

Comment: Also, do you recommend that I disable preload or enable it?

Comment: I recommend setting to the default `auto`, browsers are clever and have more info on the user than we do. Loading metadata won't make your page so slow. And if you don't start playing the media, in a lot of browsers your preloading won't work (i.e they don't load media if not needed).

Comment: I updated my question